# Is it mandatory for all the nodes in a Corda network to have the same version of Cordapp deployed?

Tags: corda

Is it mandatory for all the nodes in a Corda network to have the same Cordapp deployed? What if some nodes are having different version? Will the nodes be able to participate in a transaction if they have different versions of Cordapp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not mandatory. The version of the same CorDapp deployed in different nodes does not have to be the same, as long as the new version does not break the compatibility with the previous one, so making it impossible for the counterparty to participate to the transactions using the old version. The considerations to make are listed [in the doc](https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.8/upgrading-cordapps.html), but I report them here as well:

- Flow versioning
- State and contract versioning
- State and state schema versioning
- Serialisation of custom types

For example, if the new version of the CorDapp change things like the order of some `send()` and `receive()`, or the object type passed to the Responder flow, etc the transaction will fail.

Comment: so if there are different versions, need to handle that using version number so that it is always backward compatible.
Is there a mechanism to publish what versions are supported in a node? (especially when the node owners are different organizations)

Comment: Not exactly. But there are other things you may be interested to: https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.7/api-contract-constraints.html#types-of-contract-constraints